# Binding elements of list without MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, data-binding

I'm working on an application where I need to display the contents of the list. The problem is that I can't use mvvm. I tried to do this by binding data directly from the cs file. The list has been bound, Grid has the correct number of rows. I have no idea how to bind list items.

I tried to do it like this.

The binding list works

```
<dg:DataGrid x:Name="temp" BindingContext="{x:Reference ClassName}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding list}" SelectionEnabled="True"  
           RowHeight="50" HeaderHeight="50" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
           Margin="0,10,0,0" HeaderBackground="#85807a">
```

And i try to bind element in column like that. I need to use entry because column has to be editable.

```
<dg:DataGridColumn Title="temp" PropertyName="model_field" Width="1.8*">
                <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                            <Entry Text="{Binding model_field}" BindingContext="{Reference list}"></Entry>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridColumn>
```

and that

```
<dg:DataGridColumn Title="temp" PropertyName="model_field" Width="1.8*">
                <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                            <Entry Text="{Binding model_field}"></Entry>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridColumn>
```

But with no luck.

this is the content page section

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:dg="clr- 
  namespace:Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid"
         x:Class="NamespaceName.ClassName" x:Name="ClassNamex"
         BackgroundImage="background.jpg"
         NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
```

this is cs file

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ClassName : ContentPage
{
    public List<MyModel> list { get; set; }
    public ClassName ()
    {
        list = GeneralServices.selectedAWD.ElemList;                 
        InitializeComponent();
        title.Text = "Elements:" + 
        GeneralServices.selectedAWD.DocumentNumber; 
    } 
}
```

and the model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string model_field { get; set; }     
}
```

Comment: which specific datagrid are you using?

Comment: I get it from nuget, its Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid

Comment: if you hardcode a value in your Entry does it display?

Comment: Yes it displays

Comment: `<Entry Text="{Binding model_field}" />` should work.  Are you positive that your model contains data in that field?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that with debugging. I am sure

Comment: @Nove124 Hi, `dg:DataGrid` need to bind `ItemsSource` .

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with adding **ItemsSource="{Binding list}"**' to **dg:DataGrid** :

```
 <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" SelectionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTeam}" ActiveRowColor="#8899AA">

...

<dg:DataGrid/>
```

Then  `<Entry Text="{Binding model_field}"></Entry>` in `dg:DataGridColumn` can work.

```
<dg:DataGridColumn Title="temp" PropertyName="model_field" Width="1.8*">
      <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate >
                   <Entry Text="{Binding model_field}"></Entry>
              </DataTemplate>
       </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridColumn>
```

Here is [official sample](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid) for reference.